# Jquery validate error messages not showing up

Tags: html, jquery, validation

i have an array of inputs generated upon a press of a button. the index is maintained using a global variable `numInput` set to 0. This is the first HTML of the input.

```
<label><span>First name</span>
<input placeholder="First name" type="text" name="fName[0]" id="fName"></label>
```

This is the `addmore` button, which increments `numInput` and appends the new and mostly the same HMTL with different index

```
$(document).on('click','#addmore',function(){
  numInput++;
  var html = '<label><span>First name</span>
  <input placeholder="First name" type="text" name="fName['+numInput+']" id="fName"></label>';
  $("#frm").append(html);   
  rerunRules();         
});
```

Here is my validate method. I did not create the `message` object here...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#frm').validate({
    highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
      $(element).fadeOut(function() {
        $(element).fadeIn();
      });
    },              
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      error.appendTo(element.prev("span"));
    },
  });
});
rerunRules();
```

instead I changed the defaults:

```
<script>        
  jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    required: "- This field is required."
  });
</script>
```

The `rerunRules()` is a function that I had to call to "reinject" the rules everytime a new HTML is generated. It is also called right after `validate()` because the `fName` rules are in it.

```
function rerunRules(){
  $.each( $('input[name^="fName"]'), function () {
    $(this).rules('add', {
      required: true
    })
  });
}
```

Contrary to what I expected, the error message appears on the first `fName[0]` just as where its meant to be (to the previous `span`) but doesnt appear on the next generated HTML from the button. The validate works (wont proceed when I dont enter proper data), the highlight works, but no error message.

Comment: You generate elements with duplicate IDs, first adjust your code that it generates valid HTML.

Comment: Never occurred to me that the `validate` takes note of IDs as it reads the name attribute. I have since eliminated the `id` from every generated HTML and it now works.